# rails 3.2.16, ubuntu 12.04 - _rails_command:1: job table full or recursion limit exceeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-12.04, ruby-2.0, oh-my-zsh

I have rvm using ruby 2.0.0 on rails 3.2.16 and zshell trying to make a new project... when I run:

rails project_name I am getting the following error:
_rails_command:1: job table full or recursion limit exceeded

Comment: type ``rails new project_name``

Comment: same error.. same error in Guake, Terminal.

Comment: I actually get that error for any command I run beginning with rails (rails -v) every time

Comment: Ok I digged some deeper and it seems to be a problem with zsh, but I cant find any solution to that :/

Comment: Yeah thanks for your efforts man, I couldn't find anything either. I ended up just switching back to bash to create the project and it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using rbenv and zsh. I am not able to consistently reproduce the problem, but it seems to be related to **oh-my-zsh**'s **rails plugin**. That plugin contains an alias for rails

```
alias rails='_rails_command'
```

and a function definition for _rails_command

```
function _rails_command () {
  if [ -e "bin/rails" ]; then
    bin/rails $@
  elif [ -e "script/rails" ]; then
    ruby script/rails $@
  elif [ -e "script/server" ]; then
    ruby script/$@
  else
    rails $@
  fi
}
```

Once the problem appears, if I unalias the rails command, it functions normally.

```
unalias rails
```

Again, I was unable to reproduce the problem once I applied this fix, even after re-aliasing rails.

Comment: This is actually a workaround. After running the `unalias rails` command, all subsequent rails commands complete without error in zsh.